# php search is not displaying the database record

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database created in phpmyadmin, with few columns and data inserted.Right now i can display the table with record in the browser. But what i want is to display a particular value by filtering from the database.the following is the piece of code i have written. At this moment if I input any value into the search field it doesn't sort out, and do nothing.

```
        <?php
    if(isset ($_POST['search']))
    {
        $valueToSearch=$_POST['valueToSearch'];
        //$query="SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE CONCAT (`ISBN`, `Title`, `Author`)LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
        $query="SELECT * FROM books WHERE CONCAT ('ISBN', 'Title', 'Author')LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
        $serach_result=filterTable($query);
    }else{
        $query="SELECT * FROM books";
        $serach_result=filterTable($query);
    }

    function filterTable($query){

        $connect=mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "bookstore-new");
        $filter_result=mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        return $filter_result;
  }
    ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>

    <title>Lab 4</title>

    <style>
    table, tr, th, td 
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <form action="bookstorewebdev.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="value to search" >
    <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Filter" ><br><br>
   <table>
    <tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
  </tr>
      <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($serach_result)):?>
 <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $row['ISBN'];?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $row['Title'];?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $row['Author'];?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endwhile;?>

  </table>
 </form>
 </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are `'ISBN', 'Title', 'Author'` columns? Current code is concating that as a string so you are comparing `ISBNTitleAuthor`. This also is open to SQL injections as well.

Comment: You should add validations in your code such as what is shown in the PHP manual: `if (!mysqli_query($connect, "YOUR SQL")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
}`

Comment: Can you post database table screenshot ?

Comment: Furqan Aziz, actually because of the current reputation level i cant add any image. However, can u plese see my new issue that I have commented against UserName's answer. thank u.

Comment: chris85, i think u pointed out a good point here. but i havent got clearly. can u be a bit more specific? Ya, they r the columns. Is having Concat a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your html form have:

```
<input type="submit" name="Search" value="Filter">
```

`Search` variable, but in php you check `search`. `Search` != `search`

---

You do not check the variable `valueToSearch`. It is can be empty.
Request will fail.

---

About `concat` said *chris85*. Why do you need this?

Comment: UserName, thank u, there I had mistake, it works now. the only remaining problem is if i hit filter button more than once, it then display the whole table again. but it is supposed to show only the filtered result, no matter how many times i press the filter button.